# Sprite Kit Make an inverse SKCropNode

Tags: crop, mask, fill, inverse

I need to make an inverse crop I need to make that instad to crop the fill mask crop the  not fill area of the mask, I don´t know if it is possible , any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: See the way the trees and stuff are made less opaque in the Apple Adventure sample code